# Pusher- Triger an event from android using the POST

Tags: android, pusher

I am new on using the  pusher service.

At the moment i am not finding any documentation on how to trigger an event from the android application.

Of course I can subscribe to the events being pushed by the server but i don't know how to perform a POST request from android to pusher application website.

It seems that all the libraries available do not target android framework.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Events are triggered using the `.trigger` method; for example:

```
channel.trigger("client-myEvent", "{\"myName\":\"Bob\"}");
```

See [the documentation on triggering events from `pusher-websocket-java`](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-java#triggering-events).

This feature, where clients trigger events directly, is called ["client events"](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events). You could also have your clients trigger events indirectly, with a post to your server, followed by your server publishing a message.

Comment: Hi James, Thank you very much for pointing out this library. I was just checking that the events can be triggered in a private channel. I was wondering if it is also possible to trigger them in a public channel. I am currently implementing and android chat and i would like not to use an external personal server. In that case can i post directly to appi.pusher server. Unfortunately i can't find any related tutorial.

Comment: @peter it's not possible to trigger [client events](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events) on a public channel. "Client events can only be triggered on private and presence channels because they require authentication." If you really need to trigger events on a public channel from a client, you can do this indirectly via your server.

Comment: Thank you James. I got a response from a pusher guy, using the online support confirming that the pusher-websocket-java library can trigger events using only private or presence channel. In order to trigger events on public channel the POST method should be used following the syntax and the API described in their webiste. In support to this there exists a python library named : PythonPusherClient-master, which can trigger events on the public channels using POST method.